# Printing on Yocto MiniDisplay on System Startup

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-12.04, autostart, lcd

I have developed a C application and I am also using a Yocto_MiniDisplay,which prints some messages of application. I need to start the application on System Start up , so that in display it shows "Welcome". I am not able to start automatically on system startup. I am also using a virtualhub application for yoctopuce devices.

How to add time out in starting an application in ubuntu? What is the best way to add our application to system start up?

Comment: You may insert a starton script in `/etc/init`.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you declare as system start. If you want it to display a message at power on, you are seemingly out of luck: (from the Yocto manual)

> Startup sequence When your Yocto─MiniDisplay is powered on, it runs the yocto.seq sequence which is hard- coded inside the module. Since the Yocto─MiniDisplay's file system is not persistant you
>   cannot configure it to make it play a custom sequence at startup. But you can disable it: just configure the Yocto─MiniDisplay to play a non existant sequence at startup.

If it should be shown when Linux is starting, you could add a startup script in /etc/init.d